# aspx file path directory is correct but document won't load.

Tags: c#, asp.net, vbscript

This is my first day in ASP.NET class. My assignment was to install IIS10 Express, then find the iis10.exe file in the user directory, run it, and copy the lab0.aspx document into Note++ coded in Visual Basis. After that I type the URL http://localhost:8080/lab0.aspx. I'm suppose to see the output in my browser. Instead I get a 404 error. I know I'm doing something correct because when I type localhost in the URL I see the Internet Information Services page. In my computer directory I see the aspx file. Here is what is looks like. Yet I can't figure out what I need to do next. Online I visited I looked up ISAPI extensions module, CGI, Internet Information Services Manager, etc. I'm here to ask for some help to steer me in the right directions. The file is where it's suppose to be, so why doesn't it load in the browser? I been going in circles for hours. 
[image: This is the path to the file.]

Comment: can you try http://localhost/lab0.aspx

Comment: what is the extension of your file "lab0"? "lab1" has a icon for asp, "lab0" not

Comment: When I try localhost/lab0.aspx I get this message "Server Error in '/' Application." My extension for both lab0 and lab1 is lab0.aspx lab1.aspx.

Comment: I had xampp server on my computer which conflicted with IIS Express. I didn't know that only one server is allowed per computer. I saved lab0.aspx in wwwroot  directory and it loaded successfully.